# How to track down double pointer usage mistakes

Tags: delphi, pointers

Recently I've ported a huge chunk of code form C++ to Delphi (over 1mb of C code). The code is full with pointers. Despite project compiling and working well for 99% of the time, I'm seeing some weird results from time to time, which leads me to think there might be bugs with pointer handling - indeed, I've already found a couple. The problem is that they are really hard to track down without any clues/hints from compiler.

Maybe you have some tips, for such cases:

```
var
  a: PSingle;

GetMem(a, SizeOf(Single));

a^ := 1.1;

// Call func declared as - someFunc(aIn: PSingle);

someFunc(@a); // <<-- Bug here. I mistakely added @ while porting. 
              // someFunc needs PSingle, but gets a PPSingle instead
```

In the example, there's erroneous `@` inserted. Program does not crash, just deals with that erroneous data and keeps running. I need a way of finding such cases where "Pointer to a Pointer to a Value" gets passed instead of "Pointer to a Value".

How do you track down pointer bugs like these?

Comment: How someFunc is defined is C++ code and in your Delphi code?

Comment: @MBo: How knowing that is going to help?

Comment: I wanted to propose var-parameters, when possible, to reduce the number of errors associated with the wrong types

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "typed @ operator" compiler option is designed to detect exactly that kind of mistake. When it's disabled, the expression `@a` has type `Pointer`, which is compatible with all pointer types. Enable the option, and the same expression has type `^PSingle`, which is not compatible with the expected `PSingle`.

I recommend turning on that option in all projects; it baffles me that Delphi doesn't make that option the default all the time.

You can modify the state of that option within your code with the `$T+` and `$T-` compiler directives.

---

Another thing you can do is convert your code to use more idiomatic Delphi. For example, pass the argument by reference instead of by pointer value. Change the definition of the argument:

```
procedure someFunc(var arg: Single);
```

With that declaration, passing `@a` will be an error that the compiler will find and forbid. You would instead pass `a^`, or you could even get rid of the pointer entirely and just declare `a` as a plain `Single` rather than `PSingle`.

Just because the original code was written in C and C-style C++, it doesn't mean your Delphi code has to look like it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob! Typed @ sounds like a best shot. I'm hesitant to convert the code to Delphi so deeply, since that will break a lot of similarity and make the conversion of future C++ patches to Delphi more troublesome. The code in question is Recast Navigation.

Comment: I share Rob's bafflement. A C or C++ compiler would not accept `float**` where `float*` is expected. Quite why Delphi will has always amazed me.

Comment: It's not that Delphi does the equivalent of accepting `float**` in place of `float*`, @David; it doesn't do that. Rather, it does the equivalent of letting `&a` have type `void*` instead of `decltype(a)*` *and* giving `void*` implicit conversions to all other pointer types. It would be nice if Delphi had neither of those behaviors, but disabling just one is sufficient to prevent the mistake exhibited in this question.

Comment: @Rob In an ideal world, neither would be acceptable

Comment: @RobKennedy, @DavidHeffernan: I've got a bit of an issue with Typed@, it does not always enforced @ to be properly typed. Example: `dtVsub(@sdir[0], @q[0], @p);` Here all three arguments are `array [0..2] of Single`, but the compiler lets me get away with adding `[0]` to just first two of them, ignoring the third. Is this a known problem and is there a fix/workaround of sorts, maybe you heard about? Thanks.

Comment: @Krom We've no idea how you function is defined. Why aren't you using var oparameters?

Comment: I don't know what `dtVsub` is. Are all of its formal parameters declared identically?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear from the text. Declaration is `procedure dtVsub(dest: PSingle; v1, v2: PSingle);`. All args are used within the procedure. Looks like a compiler glitch.

Comment: There's no compiler bug in this area

Comment: Why is it not a bug? Procedure needs `dest: PSingle; v1, v2: PSingle` and is allowed to be called with Typed@ with just `@sdir[0], @q[0], @p`. All three arguments are `array [0..2] of Single`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
  someFunc(@a);
```

You are adding a pointer to a pointer not the pointer it self.

Let me make you an example:

uses
  Math;

function Somefunc(value: pSingle): Single;
begin
  Result := (value^ + 1.1)
end;

```
procedure TForm23.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: pSingle;
  b: Single;
begin
  GetMem(a, SizeOf(Single));
  a^ := 1.1;

  //Example 1:
  b := Somefunc(a);
  Caption := BoolToStr(CompareValue(2.2, b, 0.00001) = 0., True); //Caption: True

  //Example 2:
  b := Somefunc(@a); //NOTE @a
  Caption := BoolToStr(CompareValue(1.1, b, 0.00001) = 0., True); //Caption: True
  FreeMem(a);
end;
```

As you see in the first example the actual value are changed, while in example 2 the value og a remains unchanged because you parse the pointer to the pointer and therefor it is the pointer you chanhe and not the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you just stated the obvious. There is a bug and it is exactly like you describe it. Question is - How to locate such bugs in code?

Comment: The noly arround it - that I know - is to change the code :


function Somefunc(value: Single): Single;
begin
  Result := (value + 1.1)
end;

Comment: Sadly that is not viable, as the ported code in question is ~1mb and is 99% working well. Rewriting half of it just to fix a few bugs is .. unoptimal at least. Not to mention performance losses tied with that and possibility to introduce much more new bugs.

Comment: Try to compile your project with {$T+}

Comment: You might want to rewrite your answer focusing on that. The way it is now is not very helpful. Sorry

Comment: @Krom why do you think that using ref params rather than passing pointers performs worse?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I did not said exactly that. There's a lot going on in that code and PSingle example is the least of it. You can take a look at the code at github - RecastNavigationDelphi.